# Get responses from php (SweetAlert)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, sweetalert

I want to make form html look like this :

```
<script>
    function name()
    {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var url_send     = 'send.php';

        $.ajax({
            url     : url_send,
            data    : 'name='+name,
            type    : 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success : function(pesan){
                    $("#result").html(pesan);
            },
        });
    }
    </script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap-sweetalert.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/sweetalert.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/sweet-alert.css">
        <form action="#" method="post">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="name();">
    <div id="result"></div>
```

and this is `send.php`

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
if($name) {
echo 'success';
} else {
echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

And the problem is,how i show SweatAlert modal,when result of php is `Success` Sweatalert will show `Success Modal`.And when `failed` it will show `Failed Modal` ?
Now what must i edit to my script?

Comment: Where is your javascript/jQuery - ajax call?

Comment: from the looks he hasn't got one

Comment: Edited. Please answer :(

Comment: you have a form and an input type submit?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are expecting code with jquery ajax;
See the code below;

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#submit").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name_val = $("#name").val();
    $.post( "send.php", {name_send:name_val}, function(data){
        if (data == 'success'){
            swal("Good job!", "Nice work!", "success");
            return false;
            }else{
            swal("Here's a message!", "Please type a name");
            }
    });
});


});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

send.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name_send'];
if($name) {
echo 'success';
} else {
echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        url     : url_send,
        data    : {name: name},
        type    : 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success : function(pesan){
                $("#result").html(pesan);
        },
    });
```

in your ajax code you placed `data    : 'name='+name,`   , please have a look at what i did , maybe that helps

Jquery ajax accepts object in data parameter `data: {key:value}`. In the question we are using string as a parameter to data of jquery ajax

Comment: I just edited my answer , Please let me know if still have any problem .